# Uninstall bundle.js

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have react project which I developed it before. I did try to use it for similar project but want to do so I need to have it's own budle.js file. I am unable to uninstall bundle.js and reinstall it. I also tried it to delete from the folder and try to install it but not coming in ?
Any help I appreciate!

I have used 
`npm install bundle update --group development` 
But not seeing any change

Comment: What is your question?  Where is your code?

Comment: It's more of a terminal question/package question

Comment: I want to uninstall bundle.js and reinstall it

Comment: when I say `npm run bundle` ===> having an error `npm run bundle
npm ERR! missing script: bundle
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/mo/.npm/_logs/2-08-23T15_1
0_28_713Z-debug.log